# Discord.py VoiceChannel.members doesn't count members already in voice channels before boot

Tags: python, discord.py

The `Guild.VoiceChannel.members` attribute only updates when a user leaves / joins a voice channel, and it only updates for that user. I want to make sure that when my bot is running, it gets the accurate number of people in voice channels rather than none. Is there any method that handles this?

This code will run through all Guilds and Voice Channels, printing members. However, if a member was already in a voice channel before the bot was started, they will be ignored.

```python
  async def update(self):
    print('loop')
    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
        for vc in guild.voice_channels:
            for member in vc.members:
                print(member.name)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This seems to be a bug on discord.py, did you report it?

Comment: @elitegamer88 I did now

Comment: I hope its fixed, in the mean time there may be a work around.